# Show only the 5 last lines from a txt file

Tags: php, file

I want to use a file `url.txt` that is always updated, where the latest data is always added to the bottom of the file.

i used this script:

```
$file = fopen("url.txt","r");
while(! feof($file)){
  echo fgets($file). "<br />"; 
}
fclose($file);
```

I can only read all of the content within the file.
but I just wanted to get the 5 last lines and display them on the web.

Comment: Why not use `file("url.txt")` to read it into an array? Then it's easy to get the last 5 elements of the array.

Comment: as suggested by barmar, you should use file() for an easy job

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script

```
$f=file("url.txt");
$last=array_slice($f, -5);
echo implode("<br>",$last);
```

In case you want to analyze a real huge file you could use a shell command to only get the latest 5 lines in a sseparate file like:

```php
shell_exec("tail -n 5 url.txt > /tmp/phptail_file");
echo nl2br(file_get_contents("/tmp/phptail_file"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read" It will **show** only the last 5 lines. Is your file huge? or what is the problem still?

Comment: Maybe your file is not separated into lines by a usual **newline**?? Can you please add the last 6 lines of your file to your question by editing it? use the "Code Snippet" Button to shiów it as it is

Answer (score 0):

You can get to array and then display it.

```
$file = fopen("url.txt","r");
$data = array();
while(! feof($file))
      $data[] = fgets($file); 
fclose($file);
$count = count($data);
for($i = 4; $i <= 0; $i--)
      echo $data[$count - $i] . "<br>";
```